# How many outlets in 4 inch box?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Can I put two duplex receptacles in a 4 inch box (depth is 2 1/8") without overfilling it?  I will use #12 AWG with each receptacle on its own circuit (MWBC).

Wondering if I need to upgrade to a 4 11/16 box.

Comment: Be sure that your breakers for your MWBC are a properly common-trip & handle-tied so that both circuits are dead when a future person (including future you) go to work on them. Don't want someone getting a nasty shock finding out the hard way that there are 2 different circuits in each box.

Comment: The breakers don’t have to be common trip but many cases a double pole breaker is cheaper than 2 singles and a Handel tie

Comment: I defer to @EdBeal significantly greater electrical/code knowledge...

Comment: Surprisingly, the NEC §240.15(B)(1) says *Except where limited by 210.4(B), individual single-pole circuit breakers, with or without identified handle ties, shall be permitted as the pro- tection for each ungrounded conductor of multiwire branch circuits that serve only single-phase line-to-neutral loads.*  In 2011 they actually added a note to 210.4(B) pointing to the single-pole thing, too; they must recognize there was a lot of confusion about the handle ties.

Comment: @jeff wheeler , code has gone through significant changes in the 9 years since the 12 code was adopted. handle ties are required for most states and for multiwire branch circuits they were specifically required by 210.4.B. disconecting means. Each multiwire branch circuit shal be provided with a means that will simultaneously disconnect all ungrounded conductors at the point where the branch circuit originates.  96 code  if it supplied the same yoke, I actually looked these references up as I have all the books since the mid 70’s when I was an apprentice, bad info on web so I found the books.

Comment: 2 half-circuits in a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit are actually the same circuit.  Remember you will need to figure out GFCI and/or AFCI!

Comment: @FreeMan: Do any common-trip breakers provide any means of identifying which leg triggered the overload?

Comment: Not a clue. One of the electricians would have to answer. I was just passing along the warnings I've learned hanging out here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Raised exposed work cover, or flush cover?

4 x 4 x 2-1/8 is 30.3 cubic inches. That fits 13 "counts" of 12 Gauge at 2.25 cubic inches per count. If using a raised cover they typically add 6.5 cubic inches or so.

What is a count? A wire terminating in the box, a wire passing though the box, 2 counts per yoke device (ie, a receptacle) 1 count for all grounds (unless using NEC 2020 where additional ground wires [**edit:** beyond 4] count as 1/4 of a wire...) ***Edit:** right, I don't use NM/B, and if I do I use clamps that are external to the box. If you use clamps **internal** to the box they add 1 to the count.*

If the outlets are on one circuit, you presumably have 3 wires in (hot neutral ground) 2 wires out, and 4 "wires" for the two yoke devices.

9 * 2.25 = 20.25 which is less than 30.3 so you are good. *(even with clamps in the box)*

If the two receptacles are on different circuits, 5 wires in, 4 wires out, 4 for devices. 29.25 inches which is less than 30.3 so you are good.

**Edit:** Ah, you said MWBC, so subtract a wire each way (one neutral in and out, not two) still good. And remember to pigtail your neutrals.

Pigtails (wires that do not leave the box) are, incidentally "free" (they don't add to wire count.)

Wires that pass though without connecting to anything in the box count 1 **unless** they are 12" or longer, in which case they count 2. This effectively differentiates between "just passing through" and "leaving enough to a possible future connection" since you are supposed to have 6" for a connection.

As with conduit fill, not being right up against maximum box fill is more comfortable to work in.

Comment: This will have a raised cover.  I wanted each outlet on its own circuit.  The plan was to install 8 outlets along one wall in 4 separate boxes.  Four outlets on one breaker, four on another, so I'm actually running two sets of conductors through here.   Don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Should fit fine.

Answer (score 5):

### A Multi-Wire Branch Circuit is one circuit

2 "circuits" fed into a single cable with a shared neutral is a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit or MWBC.  It is one circuit.

Further, the two breakers need to be handle-tied, or they need to be a 2-pole (NOT duplex) breaker.  There must be 240V across the 2 hots (but on the upside, you can fit 240V receptacles there e.g. NEMA 6-15, 6-20 or combo 5-15/6-15 receps, which do exist).

### GFCI/AFCI will be a special challenge

AFCI requirements are difficult to meet in a multi-wire branch circuit. You need to us a 2-pole AFCI breaker which are rare.  GFCI needs to be addressed one of 3 ways:

- A 2-pole GFCI breaker
- GFCI receptacles *at every single receptacle location*
- GFCI receptacles at the first recep location, and then dual 12/2 cables or 12/2/2 beyond that point (so no more sharing a 12/3).

### 4" boxes are fine for non-GFCI...

I do it all the time.  Your wire count will be as follows:

- 3 conductors coming inward
- 3 conductors going out
- 4 "conductor" count for the 2 receptacles (2 each).
- 1 "conductor" count to cover up to 4 ground wires.
- Pigtails, mandatory on the neutral wire, are free.

That's 11 "conductors" at 2.25 cubic inches each for #12, so 24.75 cubic inches.  A normal 4x4x1-1/2 box (21") with a domed cover (6"+) will suffice.

### ... for GFCI, you'll want 4-11/16" (120mm) boxes

That is a practical limitation due to the bulk of GFCI receps; a 4x4 box will simply be too tight to effectively work with.  Also a 4x4 domed cover will require mutilating the GFCIs to fit.

It's not a statutory limitation, for GFCIs the requirement is the same as above.

4-11/16" boxes are expensive ($6-7) at the big-box store and their lids are scarce. Try a real electrical supply for a price more in the $2-3 range, you may need to go there anyway for a 2-gang Decora domed cover.

Comment: Hey Harper.  You said "GFCI receptacles at the first recep location, and then dual 12/2 cables or 12/2/2 beyond that point (so no more sharing a 12/3)."  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of an MWBC?  I'm a little fuzzy on the purpose of MWBCs, but it seems you use them for two readons: 1. You run one cable instead of two, 2. You share neutrals (one less wire in your run).  Seems like GFCIs ruin this.